# Facebook oAuth Access Token supposedly "never" expiring

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

I'm using the extended access token system to extend oAuth tokens issued by 60 days. This system is working well however one user was reporting that they had to keep resigning in. When debugging his access token these were the results:

```
Application ID
54321
Application
User ID 
12345
Joe Blogs
Issued  
1358275114 (21 hours ago)
Expires 
Never
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  email friends_events manage_pages publish_actions rsvp_event user_birthday user_events user_location
```

Facebook deprecated `offline_access` in October which was supposedly the only way to generate such a "never expiring" access token. To confirm my question: why am I seeing a never ending access token and one that does not expire in 60 days?

Comment: Its really weird. I tried getting the extended token for `APP1` , I got the `2 months` expiry token, then i tried for my `APP2` , I got the `never` expiring token (same as in your case). Is that  a bug.

Comment: Probably a bug, i tried again and again, sometimes i got `2 months token` and sometimes `never expiring`!!!

Comment: Huh seems like a bug then, will file a report now. Thanks for the confirmation +1

Comment: I wonder if it's because the session backing the token may have existed before the migration

Comment: We never used offline_access even when it was supported so it seems unlikely it's a carry over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That access token has `manage_pages` permission - if you obtained a 60 day user access token, then used that to retrieve a page access token, the user access token linked to the (infinite) page access token also becomes non-expiring

See Scenario 5 on https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ for details

Comment: The site never queries the [User ID]/accounts endpoint therefore it cannot be through this scenario.

Comment: Then what are you using manage_pages permission for? That's still the most likely cause but i thought the access token expiry extension happened once a page access token was created and tied to the user access token -  Are you doing ads management or anything else which will trigger an infinite access token?

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake - it does in fact query this endpoint to access what Pages the customer owns. Would doing this therefore extend the endpoint or does this query return a 3rd access token that does not expire?

Comment: Querying /me/accounts returns the page access tokens for those pages as part of the results, which also causes the user access token to be extended to not expire